# Struggling with simulating N rolls for K dice

Tags: r

The function `dice` takes a parameter `n`, representing number of rolls for a single six-sided die. It returns a vector of length `n` that has elements that are integers b/w 1 and 6. I have created the following code for the dice function below. It seems to run properly when I test it.

```
dice <- function(n) {
     x <- c(1:6)
     sample(length(x), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = x)

   }
```

The function kdice takes two parameters, n and k. The parameter n is denoted for number of rolls done. The number of dice rolled is represented by parameter k. The function should return the sum of the k dices, rolled n times. Somehow I have to implement dice() within this function. Below is what I have completed thus far, however the function returns nothing. I have an If and Else statement to make sure that at least 1 dice was rolled at least 1 time. While loop is to make the sum of NumofDice is outputted until it reaches n. Would appreciate any insights, especially how to incorporate the function Dice() in kdice().

```
kdice <- function(k, n){
  NumofDice <- sample(1:6, size = k, replace = TRUE)
  RollCount = 0
      if(k>0 && n>0) {
         while(RollCount < n) {
           RollCount = RollCount + 1
           sum(NumofDice)
         }
    }
      else {
        print("No number of dices were rolled")
    }

}
```

Comment: Do be careful with the `prob` argument. The default for `sample` is equal probabilities for each side of the die. You set `prob = 1:6`, which would mean the probability of a `1` is 1/21, prob of 2 is 2/21, prob of 3 is 3/21, etc. (Since `21` is `sum(1:6)`). Leave the argument blank to use the equal probability default.

Comment: This is kind of confusing because rolling n dice k times is the same as rolling n*k dice.  I think you have a problem  because you are using length(x) instead of x as the vector being sampled.  Length x will just be e.g. 6.

Comment: Ok I'll get rid of the prob and use x in place of length(x). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
kdice <- function(k, n){
  if(k>0 && n>0){
    replicate(n, sum(sample(c(1:6),k, replace=TRUE)))
  }
  else {
    print("No number of dices were rolled")
  }
}

kdice(4,2)
```

```
[1] 15  8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining `kdice` using `replicate` + `colSums` like below

```
kdice <- function(k, n) {
  tryCatch(
    colSums(matrix(replicate(n, dice(k)), nrow = k)),
    error = function(e) print("No number of dices were rolled")
  )
}
```

which give result like

```
> kdice(4, 5)
[1] 17 14 22 13 11

> kdice(4, 0)
[1] "No number of dices were rolled"
```